# What's the best way to migrate to ServiceStack authentication framework when stuck with my_aspnet_* tables

Tags: mysql, authentication, servicestack

I'm not quite ready to change up all my user/auth tables from the MySQL user/roles/profile provider format, but am moving off of MVC to ServiceStack.

Is there a pre-built IUserAuthRespository and/or CredentialsAuthProvider somewhere that can be used, or do I need to build one to provide this mapping?

If I need to build one, I assume implementing at the IUserAuthRepository level is the cleanest?  Is there a minimum set of methods required to implement basic login/logout (and administrative "switch user" impersonation) functionality?

I tried implementing a custom CredentialsAuthProvider, which seems to work, but I'm unable to get local posts for impersonation to use the proper provider.  Looking for a solution to that, I realized that maybe its better to implement the repository instead.

EDIT:
My current registration of the custom auth provider is:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
{
    container.Resolve<MySqlCredentialsAuthProvider>() //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
}));
```

And calling code for the local post to the AuthenticateService is:

```
 [RequiredRole(SystemRoles.Administrator)]
 public object Any(ImpersonateUser request)
 {
       using (var service = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>()) //In Process
       {
           //lets us login without a password if we call it internally
           var result = service.Post(new Authenticate
           {
               provider = AuthenticateService.CredentialsProvider,
               UserName = request.Username,
               //Password = "should-not-matter-since-we-are-posting-locally"
           });
           return result;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Integrating with existing User Auth tables

If you want to use your existing User/Auth tables, the easiest solution is to ignore the UserAuth repositories and [implement a Custom CredentialsAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) that looks at your existing database tables to return whether their Authentication attempt was successful.

Implement `OnAuthenticated()` to populate the rest of your typed `IAuthSession` from your database, e.g:

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, 
        string userName, string password)
    {
        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        //Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false
    }

    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, 
        IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, 
        Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        //Fill IAuthSession with data you want to retrieve in the app eg:
        session.FirstName = "some_firstname_from_db";
        //...

        //Call base method to Save Session and fire Auth/Session callbacks:
        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        //Alternatively avoid built-in behavior and explicitly save session with
        //authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        //return null;
    }
}
```

### Importing existing User Auth tables

If you want to import them into an OrmLite User Auth tables, you would configure to use the `OrmLiteAuthRepository` in your AppHost:

```
//Register to use MySql Dialect Provider
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(dbConnString, MySqlDialect.Provider));

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new CustomUserSession(), //Use your own typed Custom UserSession type
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
        new CredentialsAuthProvider()
    }));

//Tell ServiceStack you want to persist User Info in the registered MySql DB above
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c =>
    new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

//Resolve instance of configured IUserAuthRepository
var userAuth = container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();

//Create any missing UserAuth RDBMS tables
authRepo.InitSchema();
```

Then to import your data you can use the above MySQL DB connection to select from your existing tables then use the `IUserAuthRepository` to create new Users.

```
// Open DB Connection to RDBMS
using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
{
    //Example of fetching old Users out of a custom table (use your table instead)
    var oldUsers = db.Select<OldUserInfo>();

    // Clear existing UserAuth tables if you want to replay this import
    //db.DeleteAll<UserAuthDetails>();
    //db.DeleteAll<UserAuth>();

    //Go through and create new User Accounts using Old User Info
    foreach (var oldUser in oldUsers)
    {
        //Create New User Info from Old Info
        var newUser = new UserAuth {
            UserName = oldUser.UserName,
            Email = oldUser.Email,
            //...
        };

        //Create New User Account with oldUser Password
        authRepo.CreateUserAuth(newUser, oldUser.Password);
    }
}
```

After this you'll have new User Accounts from your old User Info which you can sign in with.

Comment: Mythz, this is what I had done previously (implemented a custom CredentialsAuthProvider), however ran into issues with local requests to the AuthenticateService for impersonation from an admin.  The call i'm doing per https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#in-process-authenticated-requests is returning back an invalid username or password error, but the request never hits my custom provider.  Thoughts?

Comment: @JesseP Won't be able to tell without seeing your registration and calling code. Is it calling `CredentialsAuthProvider.IsAuthorized()`?

Comment: see edit on the original question for that info.  Thanks!

Comment: @JesseP Can't tell from here, I'm assuming its inheriting `CredentialsAuthProvider` and you've set `SkipPasswordVerificationForInProcessRequests=true`? Resolving MySqlCredentialsAuthProvider from IOC stands out as needs to be a singleton so should only have singleton/ThreadSafe deps, so I'd personally inject any deps in the constructor manually. Other than that can't see from here, would need a stand-alone repro to debug locally, otherwise you can try [debugging v4.0.44 source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/v4.0.44) using [GitLink](https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink)

Comment: Yes, i'm using a singleton instance of the MySqlCredentialsAuthProvider resolved via the IoC as ReuseScope.Container, and the skip for local requests flag as true.  I enabled the symbols server settings for debugging (per https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging, but i'll check out GitLink too).

Comment: i'm seeing that it's getting all the way to CredentialsAuthProvider.AuthenticatePrivateRequest, and then failing when it tries to get the new user (what i'm trying to impersonate) from the authRepo:   var userAuth = authRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName(userName);   It turns out I had registered IUserAuthRepository as InMemoryAuthRepository, thinking that it was just a cache or something.  it looks like i need to implement that as well now in order to do private auth maybe?

Comment: @JesseP Yeah that's the issue, you'd need to register a custom `IUserAuthProvider` that implements `GetUserAuthByUserName()` and `GetUserAuthDetails()` or override [AuthenticatePrivateRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs#L139) with a custom impl that doesn't call the userAuth repo, which I've just [made virtual in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/0a9b332dece466d26127d221afc735b87d07e633) this change is [now on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Perfect, i'll go the route of overriding AuthenticatePrivateRequest.  Thanks!